# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ListViewItem VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Dim myList As ListViewItem

    Dim JmlList As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    JmlList = lst_detail.Items.Count - 1
    i = 0

    myList = lst_detail.Items.Add(str(lst_detail.Items.Count + 1)) // error at this
    myList.SubItems.Add(txtKodeObat.Text.Trim)
    myList.SubItems.Add(txtNamaObat.Text.Trim)
    myList.SubItems.Add(txtHarga.Text.Trim)
    myList.SubItems.Add(txtQty.Text.Trim)
    myList.SubItems.Add(txtJumlah.Text.Trim)

    Dim subtotal As Double = 0

    JmlList = lst_detail.Items.Count - 1
    For i = 0 To JmlList
        subtotal = subtotal + Val(lst_detail.Items(i).SubItems(5).Text)
    Next
    txtSubTotal.Text = Format(subtotal, "##########")
    txtPPn.Text = Format(subtotal * 0.1, "##########")
    txtTotal.Text = Val(txtSubTotal.Text) + Val(txtPPn.Text)
    txtKodeObat.Text = ""
    txtNamaObat.Text = ""
    txtHarga.Text = "0"
    txtQty.Text = ""
    txtJumlah.Text = "0"
    txtKodeObat.Focus()

End Sub
```

I got error at         myList = lst_detail.Items.Add(str(lst_detail.Items.Count + 1))

i want to add from text to listitem but got null error
i have fill that textbox

Comment: Have you debugged it? Were you able to see either lst_detail or lst_detail.Items as null while running through code ? Because based on error, one of the object seems to be null.

Comment: I'm curious why you're adding 1 to Count in that line.

Comment: @hatchet to count or to numbering  the column

Comment: @Sujith i dont know how to debug and analyst the null

Comment: @Hassan if you are using Visual Studio or any other MS tools, there are many articles on debugging and running code in internet. You need to refer to those. It makes things easy for you, before you start looking into code.

Answer (score 0):

lst_detail or lst_detail.Items seems to be null. Debug the code and you should be able see one of these null. If lst_detail is null and you are trying to access lst_detail.Items it will throw "Null reference" execption - which means you are trying to access something from a object with null value.

Comment: If lst_detail or lst_detail.Items were null, then the assignment two lines above would have thrown the exception first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pull data from a specific index within the lst_detail. I didn't test the following code, but something like the following might do what you're trying to do.

myList = lst_detail.Items.Add(lst_detail.Items[lst_detail.Items.Count + 1].ToString())